# Part of background image showing below footer - Help please

Tags: image, background, footer

I created a custom page for my ecommerce store and I noticed that part of my background image is showing below my footer. It is only happening on this page so I assume there is something wrong with my new page. Anybody have any answers as to why this is happening? Thank you!

Here's the page... http://www.mmatopsupplies.com/brands/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ahaurat, much appreciated! I applied your quick fix and it worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't investigate long enough to see why it's happening, but a quick fix is adding the following css to your footer.

```
#ContainerFooter {
    margin-bottom:-20px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could add the css to your `.container.footer` class. Hope that helps!